# Excel web part vs rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, excel-services, excel-web-access-webpart, jquery-ajax

I want to DISPLAY multiple excel charts on a dashboard. I Do Not need the  functionality of the excel web part. So, what I plan on doing is getting an image of the charts via the excel rest api and appending the images to td elements on the page. Are there any resons not to take this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images will be static, but that sounds like what you want. For SharePoint Online, you will have to use the Graph API instead.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/resources-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/excel

Comment: But the only difference will be how to format the uri?